# Sequelize Associations between two models datatype error

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I want to associate two tables say tableA(user) tableB(tasks). I have created the foreign key (say userId) in tableB of datatype array Integer. Now I want to associate A and B table but is showing

```
      SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: integer[] = integer
```

I tried this :

```
   db.tableB.belongsTo(db.tableA, { foreignKey: 'userId'});

 db.tableB.findAll({
   where:{}.
   include : [{
    model: db.tableA
   }]
 })
```

Comment: Try to change the datatype of `userId` to `integer`

Comment: I want it to store multiple userIds so I m using array

Comment: Two columns involved in a foreign key must be both compatible types. If TableB has to store N data pieces for a certain user then it must be N records each one with the same userId field value.

Comment: it is like the tableB wants to store N records and each record is possible to attach with different  multiple userIds